# Error - The pre-application start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, version-control

I am currently editing a project that was opened from a source control at my business.  When trying to debug locally I get the error

> Validating Web Site
>
> : Build (web): The pre-application start initialization method Start
>   on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode threw
>   an exception with the following error message: Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\gary\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DOISAdminPortal\'
>   is denied..

Ive done some research and a lot of people say to delete the 
add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"
from the web.config file.  It was never included in the config file so that shouldn't be the issue.

Anyone have any suggestions??

Comment: So you don't have `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` in your `appSettings` section in `web.config`?

Comment: No that code is not in the web.config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files which were contained in the VS 2010 folder needed to be given permissions to the iis express user iis_iusrs.  once this was done I was able to access all files in the directory and was able to debug the page.

Comment: I had to do essentially the same thing on our build server.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Try turning off impersonation for local testing.

For my case, our web.config had the following line:

`<identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN2\admin" password="12345"/>`

under the `</system.web>` section.

This impersonated identity functioned on the production server, but when running it on my local, the user `admin` from domain `DOMAIN2` did not have the same privileges because my local machine was on a different domain say `DOMAIN3` and did not by default give `DOMAIN2\admin` any rights on the system.

One way I circumvented the issue is by turning off impersonation like follows:

`<identity impersonate="false" userName="DOMAIN2\admin" password="12345"/>`

I suppose this defaulted my settings to use the rights from the currently logged in user.